# Remove empty line / lines in PSPad using regexp

Tags: regex, editor, whitespace, pspad

I was wondering how to delete empty lines or just any line in PSPad using regexp.

It can not be done with regexp, however there is a way - so:

**I wanted to share the knowledge => *see my answer below...***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Removing the line in PSPad

PSPad (unlike e.g. Notepad++) does not allow you to remove lines using regexp at all, if you are thinking about using `^YOU_REG_EXP$` replacing with "nothing", it will not work, however *you **can** pre-clean the lines* like that.

## Removing empty lines in PSPad:

In top menu go to **Edit -> Lines manipulation** and choose one of these options:

- Remove Blank Lines Remove Redundant
- Blank Lines (leave at least one
  blank line)

[image: Removing empty lines in PSPad]